# Angular Filtering Kendo GridDataResult

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on an app where I have a dataset of records coming back in a parent component but I want to split it up based on a value and then convert it to two separate datasets that I want to pass to the child components.  My call in the parent looks like this:

```
public gridResult: GridDataResult;
public child1Result: GridDataResult;
public child2Result: GridDataResult;

this.changeService.objectChanges(gridState).pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroy$))
  .subscribe((data) => {
    this.gridResult = data;
    // this is where I think I need filter the data

    this.loading = false;
  });
```

I tried adding a filter to the data, but that's not available on a GridDataResult.  Thanks in advance.